# How to use one json label file for all the training images for YOLO-NAS

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I want to run yolo object detection Model. I have annotated the images and got the coco format.

Which I have one label annotations Json file for train, test and valid data.

when we are defining the config details to the model where will be specifying the directory for train_images and train_labels like that for test and valid

So how to pass the label.json file path in the config and run the YOLO-NAS model for object-detection.

Config example : -

```
train: path/to/train/images/
val: path/to/validation/images/

nc: number_of_classes
names: ['class1', 'class2', ..., 'classN']

# COCO-style JSON annotations
labels:
  train: path/to/train/annotations.json
  val: path/to/validation/annotations.json
```

Answer (score 0):

To train YOLO model you have to follow **YOLO Darknet txt** format. You can use this repo to convert labels from coco json to yolo txt.

https://github.com/ultralytics/JSON2YOLO

Comment: I don't want to create multiple txt files for each image labels which will consume huge amount of space instead of that can't we use the Json file directly to yolo-nas model?

Comment: As I said you cannot, as this format is required by YOLO. You can change official code, to generate annotations in YOLO format from COCO json before training and delete them from code once training is completed.